# "This workbook cannot be shared becuase privacy has been enabled for this workbook...." error message when trying to track cahnges in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

[image: message]Hello Supper User community, Need to pick your brain for this one.
I am trying to track changes in an excel spread sheet that is shared with other users. When I select Review>Track Changes>Highlight Changes I get the following Error message: "" This workbook cannot be shared because privacy is enabled for this workbook..."

Please, need your help to resolve this one. Any help is appreciated and thank you all in advance. enter image description here

Comment: Did you try the suggested method with error message?

Comment: Wow, that was embarrassing, (note to self: read the full error message). @RajeshS, yes, following the instructions in the error message resolved my problem. Thank you.

Comment: Hey @as134_user3693277,, glad to help you keep asking,, if you feel then I could post this as an Answer,, just [Check this](https://superuser.com/tour) ☺

Comment: @RajeshS, once agin, Thanks for your help, go ahead and post this as an answer, I'm good with that.

Answer (score 0):

**Caveat:** Posting this,since OP mentioned through comments above.

@as134_user3693277,, please read the error message, itself is a solution. Just follow the instruction, your get rid from the issue.